# PHP redirect work but doesnt show page in host

Tags: php, redirect

I have redirect. In debugger Chrome I see redirect and response. But I don`t see a page. Whats problem?

Redirect in php:

```
header('Location: ' . 'indexb.php');
exit;
```

What I see in debugger:
[image]

What I must see:
[image]

Local this code works fine but in host doesnt work

Comment: Why would you expect to see a page of an XHR request?

Comment: Because this redirect work on local